How to nest multiple isset() functions based on multiple forms without losing any of the form data or refreshing the browser?
I am trying to solve a php problem to find the mean of n random numbers based on the limit(n) given by user on an HTML form.
My approach was to create a Html form which asks the user to Enter the limit on a textbox like this:
screenshot 1
After clicking the submit button, I wrote a php code using if(isset()) which asks the user to enter a string of integer numbers upto n seperated by spaces and click a submit button 'Done'.
screenshot 2
Afer that, I tried to convert the string input given in the last form to an array of integers using array_map and explode function. Then I checked if the count of integers in the array was equal to the limit mentioned first. If it was, using foreach loop, calculate the sum of each numbers in the array and finally exit from the loop, calculate avg and echo it.
Here is my whole code.
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mean: n numbers</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <h2><u>Mean of n numbers</u></h2><br><br>
        Enter the limit: <input type="number" name="num"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>


        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $n = $_POST['num'];

            echo "<form method='get' > ";
            echo "Enter a string of $n numbers each digit seperated by spaces: ";
            echo "<input type='text' name='str'><br>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='sub' value='Done'><br>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        if (isset($_GET['sub'])) {

            $numstr = $_GET['str'];
            echo $numstr;
            //$numarr =  explode(" ", $numstr);
            $numarr = array_map('intval', explode(' ', $numstr));

            $s = 0;
            $counta = count($numarr);

            if ($counta != $n) {
                exit("Please enter n numbers seperated by spaces!");
            } else {
                foreach ($numarr as $i) {

                    $s = $s + $i;
                }
                $avg = $s / $counta;
                echo "<br>The mean of the given n numbers is " . $avg;
            }
        }
        ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

The problem is that the browser is refreshing to the first page itself and it's not displaying or executing the 2nd if(isset()) block.
I am new to all this. Can someone please explain in detail how to solve my problem without having to enter both the limit and string of numbers in one html form at once.
Thanks in advance.

Honestly, I think I'd solve the show/hide problem with JS instead, unless you have a specific need to go to the server. That said, you just need to echo the submitted value of num back into the HTML field's value attribute. You can use the null coalescing operating for this: https://3v4l.org/e4mP0

No matter what, mixing POST and GET here is weird, and is asking for trouble. Pick one and stick to it. Remember that the web is stateless. If you go back from client to server to client to server, you must bring over any state somehow. A common way to do this is hidden form fields, however you can use other state mechanisms like cookies or sessions, although I'd say those are overkill for this scenario.

You should probably do the dynamic prompts in JavaScript on the client, not in PHP.

"The problem is that the browser is refreshing to the first page itself" - that's because of the faulty HTML you are creating there. You can not nest forms in HTML, but that is exactly what you did there - you output your second form inside the first one. The browser's error correction mechanism will "fix" this by ignoring the second <form> tag, and adding the following input fields into your already opened form. You thought you had submitted a second, separate form via the GET here, but actually you didn't.

Thanks @ChrisHaas. As you said, I echoed the submitted value of num in the value attribute of the first html form using the null coalescing operator and it worked.

Also many thanks to everyone who commented on my question giving their valuable knowledge.
